# Build my .NET Solution using msbuild.exe programmatically and output the logs

Tags: .net, msbuild

Due to my project requirements, I need to create a application which accepts the Solution File path, target framework and other input parameters and invoke the msbuild.exe on a custom path which I gave.

I'm doing that as below.

```
var buildPath = @"C:\Program Files (x86)\MSBuild\14.0\Bin\MSBuild.exe";
        var solutionPath = @"D:\Siva\Sandbox\Samples\SandboxProject\SandboxProject.sln";
        var buildLogs = "/flp:Summary;Verbosity=minimal;LogFile=msbuild.sum";
        var process = new Process();
        process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(buildPath);
        process.StartInfo.Arguments = " " + solutionPath + " " + buildLogs;
        process.Start();
```

Comment: *Solution File path, target framework and other input parameters and invoke the msbuild* sounds like a batch file, i.e. do you really need an application for that? Also if you search for "msbuild programmatically" you'll find all info you need.

Comment: Thanks Stijn. I wrote the code to invoke the msbuild.exe and passing the solution name. Build is getting succeeded. But I'm unable to write the logs to log files. Updated my question accordingly.

Comment: Can't reproduce. this code definitely produces a logfile. Likely you are just looking in the wrong place for it: since you didn't specify a full path (which you should), the logfile goes into the current working directory..

Answer (score 0):

```
I've followed the below approach.
1) Created a Process which will invoke standalone msbuild.exe and passing the Solution Name, Dependencies as command arguments.

Custom XML Build File:

    <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
    <Project ToolsVersion="4.0" DefaultTargets="Build" xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/developer/msbuild/2003">
    <PropertyGroup>    
    <PackageDir>$(BuildPackageDir)..\packages</PackageDir>
    </PropertyGroup>
    <Target Name="RestorePackages">
    <RemoveDir Directories="$(PackageDir)" />
    <MakeDir Directories="$(PackageDir)" />    
    <Exec WorkingDirectory="$(BuildDir)" Command="NuGet.exe restore $(MSBuildSolutionDirectory) -OutputDir $(PackageDir)" />
    </Target>
    <Target Name="Build">
      <CallTarget Targets="RestorePackages"/>
    <MSBuild Projects="$(MSBuildSolutionDirectory)" Targets="Rebuild"/>
    </Target>
    </Project>

My Command Arguments:

    inputParameters.Append(" ");
    inputParameters.Append(buildSourcePath);
    inputParameters.Append(" ");
    inputParameters.Append(Constants.PROPERTYCOMMAND);
    inputParameters.Append("BuildSolutionDirectory=");
    inputParameters.Append('"');
    inputParameters.Append(buildSolutionName);
    inputParameters.Append('"');
    inputParameters.Append(" ");
    input.Parameteters.Append(Constants.PROPERTYCOMMAND);
    inputParameters.Append("BuildPackageDir=");
    inputParameters.Append('"');
    inputParameters.Append(MSBuildSolutionDirectory);
    inputParameters.Append('"');
    inputParameters.Append(" ");
    inputParameters.Append(buildLogs);
    inputParameters.Append(" ");
    inputParameters.Append(Constants.PROPERTYCOMMAND);
    inputParameters.Append("BuildDir=");
    inputParameters.Append('"');
    inputParameters.Append(buildDirectory);
    inputParameters.Append('"');

And then executes the process.

    var process = new Process();
    process.StartInfo = new ProcessStartInfo(msBuildPath);
    var frameworkType = Helpers.CheckProjectFramework(projectDirectory);
    process.StartInfo.Arguments =     
    Helpers.BuildInputParameters(projectDirectory, frameworkType);
    process.Start();

buildSourcePath -> .xml path
MSBuildSolutionDirectory -> Root path of the .sln which we are going to build
buildDirectory -> Location of the nuget.exe folder.

And in parallel creating a Log files to get the build output. I'm able to build my application.
```